# Using xpathnavigator select xpathexpression response by concatenating a constant

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have a library function which looks as below

```
private static string Parse(XPathNavigator xNav, XPathExpression xPathExpression)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        XPathNodeIterator xpathIterator = xNav.Select(xPathExpression.Clone());

        while (xpathIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            result = result + xpathIterator.Current.TypedValue + "#";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And there is a XML file which would look as below

```
<Account account_no ="100">
<Name>Hello</Name>
</Account>
```

Now I need write a xpath which would  return account_no concatenating some constant

I wrote code something like below

```
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(@"..\..\test.xml", XmlSpace.Default);
        XPathNavigator xNav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        string xpath = "concat('Account No', /Account/@account_no)";
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathExpression.Compile(xpath);
        string result = Parse(xNav, xPathExpression);
```

The result what I am expecting is account_no prefixing it with some text constant. So I wrote the xpath as concat('Account No', /Account/@account_no). But this did not work, failed at xNav.Select(). Please help me on how to write proper xpath to get the required result. I do not have liberty to make changes to parse function, whatever I can do, I should do with only xpath string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you modify your `Parse()` method to be like this:

```
private static string Parse(XPathNavigator xNav, XPathExpression xPathExpression)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    object selected = xNav.Evaluate(xPathExpression.Clone());

    XPathNodeIterator iterator = selected as XPathNodeIterator;
    if (iterator != null)
    {
        result = string.Concat(iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>()
                                       .Select(n => n.TypedValue + "#"));
    }
    else
    {
        result = selected.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I cannot make changes to Parse() method. It's part of some other generic library. Only I can play with xpath expression... :(

Comment: In that case, it's not possible to accomplish this with only an XPath expression because XPathNavigator.Select() only works with nodeset selection paths.  You could possibly do this: `string xPath = "/Account/@account_no"; result = "Account No" + Parse(xNav, XPathExpression.Compile(xPath)).TrimEnd('#');`